# Not sending any text messages

Tags: swift, twilio

I want to implement sending of text messages in my app. I'm new to this, so please bear with me.

Here is the code for the button that the user should tap when wanting to send a message:

```
   @IBAction func sendMessageButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {


        if let accountSID = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"],
            let authToken = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"] {

            let url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/\(accountSID)/Messages"
            let parameters = ["From": "123456789", "To": "987654321", "Body": "Hello from Swift!"]

            AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
                .authenticate(username: accountSID, password: authToken)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)

            }
            print(accountSID) //Does not get called
            RunLoop.main.run()
        }     
    }
```

This code is snached from [Twilio´s own guide to sending text messages from Swift](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/03/sending-text-messages-in-swift-with-twilio.html)

When I follow the guide, and build in terminal it sends the message, but when I run the app with the above code, nothing happens. Should the `package.swift`and ´main.swift´ be implemented in the project somehow? Or am I completely off target here?

**EDIT***
When I add:

```
 print(ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"])
 print(ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"])
```

to the `@IBAction func sendMessageButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton)` it return nil, but if I run the commands: `echo $TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN` and `echo $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID` it returns the correct values.

Comment: I suspect `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]` and `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]` are nil.

Comment: That was my thought as well. But how do I set them? I have ran the commands: `export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID='YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID'` and `export TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN='YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN'` in terminal from the root folder of my project. Of course with my own credentials. Is that not correct?

Comment: did you do that in the same terminal window you ran the project from? I imagine it runs in a different scope. You may need to add these to your bash_rc file (if my memory serves me correctly)

Comment: @Anvil did you get this sorted with Scriptable's advice? This blog post on the [different ways to set environment variables](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html) might help.

Comment: @philnash Thanks fot your followup. No, I'm still not able to send messages. I have set the environment variables, so that when I run the commands echo $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID and echo $TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN it returns the correct values. But the app still don't send. Could there be some other configuration I am missing or done wrong? Please se edited question

Comment: Hold on, is this within an app or with Swift on the server?

Comment: @philnash This is within an app

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The code you are following is for calling the Twilio API using Swift on the server.

We do not recommend that you make API calls to the Twilio API from an application as you will need to include or embed your Twilio crendentials to do so. A malicious user could then decompile the application and abuse your account.

Instead, we recommend that you set up a server of your own that you call from your application. The server can then keep your credentials safe. There is a blog post on [how to send an SMS from iOS in Swift](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/how-to-send-an-sms-from-ios-in-swift.html) that shows you how to do this.

Comment: Aha. I see now. Thank you for clarifying